# Question on dictionary of delegates

Tags: c#

I am writing an if/else alternative using a table driven method.

I have the following code:

```
var map = new[] 
{
    new 
    {
        Predicate = new Func<Type, bool>(type => type.IsInterface),
        Selector = new Func<Type, Delegate>(str, sww.Invoke())
    }
};
```

In the selector, I want to return a delagate which I can invoke (points to another method), or specify in line (eg (`delegate() { // Do something here. }`).

I am using (and modifying) the code from here: [Table Driven Method issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508718/table-driven-method-issue)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Delegate, you can use a specific delegate type, such as Action:

```
Selector = new Func<Type, Action>(str, sww.Invoke)
```